# Upgrading XML Schema programmatically

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd, linq-to-xml, platform

I'm in the process of having to re-write a project due to the platform vendor needing the storage mechanism be in an XElement object instead of storing in data tables that I create in their database.  It's becoming painful, and I need some insight.

I can morph my object graph to/from Xml using the XmlSerializer and read/write to/from the XElement object that I'm given, but I'm not sure how to upgrade the Xml Data when I need to change the object graph.

Has anyone confronted this, and what articles have proven the best to learn how to build such an update methodology.  Thanks.

Comment: Do I understand you want to update the XML data when you change the definition of your classes, without re-serializing?
It sounds tricky...

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what I want to do.  I'm trying to figure this out, as I don't have a choice but to handle in this method.  I recall that there is a way to overload the serialization/deserialization methods, and had thought someone had done this in the past to solve this issue.

Comment: The idea is when I need to change the definition, I can run a script of sorts that will read the old XML format into memory, make the morphs required, and then serialize out to the new XML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in this frustrating situation before...
I think this can't be done using the XmlSerializer. The XmlSerializer compiles a serialisation routine that is custom-built around your current type hierarchy. If you change that too much, the XML will become incompatible with the new class structure.

I don't think any XML Schemas get generated, the only 'schema' is the compiled ad-hoc XML serializer code.

You *could* do what you want by
1) creating *new* classes that reflect your changes,
2) deserialising the XML into the old classes,
3) applying the morph between old and new objects,
4) serialising the new objects,
5) changing names of classes to the old ones,
6) replacing the temp names in the XML,

but it's extremely painful (though it may be ok as a one-off).

If you need to cope with frequent changes (or if you use serialisation-unfriendly compilers like the current F# one), the best idea here is to write *your own* XmlSerializer (possibly using Linq2XML) that can cope with code changes.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you elaborate on the idea of using Linq2Xml and building one's own XmlSerializer?  Sounds like the route I was thinking, but wasn't sure about the whole Linq2Xml thingy.

I was thinking if the master object could hold a "version" attribute, maybe that could then be used as part of the upgrade script, whatever that could be.